# Changing output text with sed

Tags: bash, text, sed

I have problem with formating text in BASH using sed.
This is the input file:

```
recfun.o -> timeout.o (set_timeout)
recursive.o -> timeout.o (timeout)
print_recursive.o -> recursive.o (ackermann)
rec-nam.o -> timeout+.o (timeout)
```

and this shloud be the output:

```
recfunDo -> timeoutDo [label="set_timeout"];
recursiveDo -> timeoutDo [label="timeout"];
print_recursiveDo -> recursiveDo [label="ackermann"];
rec_namDo -> timeoutPDo [label="timeout"];
```

Which means this:

substitute: 
"-" for "_", then  "." for "D", then "+" for "P", but do not substitute " ->" for " _>"

I have used sed like this:

```
sed -e 's/./D/' file | sed -e 's/+/P/' | sed -e 's/-/_/'
```

But it returns the same output with just D substituted for first letter in each line.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

`.` matches any character in the pattern, hence it always changed the first letter. Escaping it as `\.` helps. The full command:

```
sed 's/\./D/g; s/+/P/g; s/-\([^>]\)/_\1/; s/(/[label="/; s/)/"];/' myfile 
recfunDo -> timeoutDo [label="set_timeout"];
recursiveDo -> timeoutDo [label="timeout"];
print_recursiveDo -> recursiveDo [label="ackermann"];
rec_namDo -> timeoutPDo [label="timeout"];
```

As Trenin notes in the comment, multiple commands separated with `;` are grouped in one sed script here. The part `s/-\([^>]\)/_\1/` uses a numbered group denoted with `\(...\)` (and refers to it as `\1` in the replacement part) and a character class inside the group: `[^>]`. This matches any character except `>`.

Comment: You might want to add some explanation.  For example, OP might not know that you can chain multiple commands with the `;`.  Also, to get around replacing `->`, you've matched `-` followed by anything other than `>`.  Good answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the  `.`

```
sed -e 's/\./D/g' file
```

Comment: Also use `/g` to do multiple replacements in the same line.

Comment: @fedorqui missed the `global`, fixed

Comment: oh, I see, sorry, I am new to bash

Comment: @user3021851 Technically, this is not a bash feature, it's just sed regex (see e.g. [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions)).

Answer (score 0):

Perl's regular expressions are handy here:

```
perl -pe 'tr/.+/DP/; s/-(?!>)/_/g; s/\((.+?)\)$/[label="$1"];/'
```